# How to send password on deployment server at time of git pull in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Can anyone help me in know how i can send password when on deployment server i do git pull in shell script.
 Please refer the below script which i am trying to run:

```
cd
cd /opt/project location
sudo git pull branch name
sudo npm install
sudo npm run build
```

Everything is working fine like job is getting started when anybody pushing code to the bitbucket  only git pull is not happening on deployment server.

Comment: If you use an ssh key you can add that to the jenkins credentials

Comment: But still while doing git pull it asks for password

Comment: I'm not sure, where to start, but I see multiple issues: `sudo`? Shouldn't be needed. Why are you executing plain `git pull` with Jenkins? You could just used `checkout` step with Jenkins Pipelines. And as said - when you use SSH for Git - you don't need passwords.